# Teehan & Lax hide header with javascript -- Hiding on scroll down, revealing on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, transition

I've been working on a website with a mobile version that has a fixed header, and I want to get the same effect while scrolling down to hide the navigation, only to reveal it when you scroll up more than 5 pixels.

Just like [teehanlax.com](http://www.teehanlax.com/story/medium/). I've given a it a shot using some code I found online, but it behaves strangely. It's hiding on scroll down, but only reveals again, seemingly... randomly.

Here is my code.

```
//Hide Header on on scroll down
        $(function(){
            var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
            $(window).scroll(function(event){
               var st = $(this).scrollTop();

               if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
                  return;

               if (st > lastScrollTop){
                   // Scroll Down
                    $("header").delay(100).queue(function() {
                        $(this).addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });

               } else {
                  // Scroll Up
                    $('header').delay(100).queue(function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("fadeOutUp").addClass("animated fadeInDown");
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });
               }
               lastScrollTop = st;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS you posted looks pretty sound, it might be more of a CSS issue. Can you post the CSS that goes along with this?

Comment: I ended up doing away with it. Just didn't seem worth the effort.